# JList keep heighlight after focus is lost

Tags: java, swing, jlist

How to keep highlight (selected item) after focus on JList is lost.

setSelectedIndex didnt reselect the item after focus lost.

```
list.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent var1) {
                if (index != -1) { 
                   list.setSelectedIndex(index); 
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent var1) {}
            
        });
```

**Solution:**

```
public class SelectedListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object file, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (index == lastIndex && lostFocus) {
                cellHasFocus = true;
            } 
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, file, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    }
```

Then add it to JList:

```
list.setCellRenderer(new SelectedListCellRenderer());
list.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void focusLost(FocusEvent var1) {
                            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                                lostFocus = true;
                            }
                        } 
                        @Override
                        public void focusGained(FocusEvent var1) {
                            lostFocus = false;
                            repaint();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]?

Comment: `JList` does not deselect the item on focus lost. If there’s such a behavior in your application, it must come from another listener in your application. Instead of adding a listener trying to fix what the first listener does (when listener notification has no guaranteed order), remove the first listener. Having two listeners fighting over the behavior on focus lost, is not a good idea.

Comment: @Holger, it is a JList in JFileChooser. I am trying to keep Item in JFileChooser selected after focus on TextField

Comment: It’s not a good idea to hack into the `JFileChooser`. The behavior is Look&Feel specific and likewise your solution will only work in particular Look&Feel implementations. Besides that, you should post solutions as answers instead of including them in the question.